# I am getting a black page as soon as i activate my LightSpeed Cache Plugin in Wordpress. I am currently using a Avada Theme. How to resolve this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a website that uses Avada Child Theme in Wordpress. For page optimization purpose I have insatlled Lightspeed Cache plugin, activating which i get black pages. I have created and attached a QUIC-Cloud account with it. Nothing changed. What should i do now so that i can enhance my website performance ?

I have tried to cron all the requests asked in the dashboard for critical CSS, etc. but nothing is happening. Is here anyone using the LightSpeed Cache Plugin who can help me with that problem ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're encountering issue with the Lightspeed Cache plugin with your Avada Child Theme on WordPress. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and improve performance:

- Ensure that your version of Avada, the Child Theme, and the Lightspeed Cache plugin are all up to date. Sometimes compatibility issues arise due to outdated software.
- Deactivate other plugins one by one to identify if there's a conflict causing the black pages. It's possible that another plugin may not be compatible with Lightspeed Cache.
- Avada is a feature-full good theme, and some customizations might conflict with caching plugins. Check if any customizations in your Avada Child Theme are causing issues. Temporarily switch to the parent Avada theme to see if the problem persists.
- Check if your server is configured correctly to work with Lightspeed Cache. Make sure your hosting environment supports the required features.
- Make sure that the cron jobs for critical CSS and other optimizations are running correctly. If they are not, you may need to investigate the server's cron configuration.